# How to pass a parameter to a regex inside an awk command

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, ksh

I am having troubles with passing a parameter to a regex inside an awk command.What seems to be the problem here? Does the regex read the parameter name instead of the value? Thanks

```
FILE=*some file here*
TEST_STRING1=test


awk -v testString1="$TEST_STRING1" 'BEGIN {

}
{
##Sample REGEX HERE
if ( $0 ~ "^testString1.* - \[.*\] - .*$") {
##DO SOMETHING HERE
            }
}
END{}
' $FILE
```

Comment: just like with any other language, a word inside a string is just a word even if it happens to be the same as the name of some variable or function or any other symbol used in the program. `"...testString1.."` is simply a string that contains the text `testString1`, it has no relationship to the variable of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use awk string concatenation:

```
if ( $0 ~ "^" testString1 ".* - \[.*\] - .*$" ) {
```

Or, do the variable substitution in the shell -- the quoting is a bit tricky

```
awk -v regex="^${TEST_STRING1}"'.* - \[.*\] - .*$'
```

Then, in awk

```
if ($0 ~ regex) ...
```